# Same-sex couple data from American Community Survey (ACS)

Tags: data-request, us-census, lgbt

I tried to find the same-sex data from ACS and collect them at the census tract level. There are some good information in the website (see below) but it doesn't specify which tables have such information.

http://www.census.gov/hhes/samesex/data/acs.html

After some research, I did find the "unmarried partner household" information from table B11009. According to census analysis, same-sex couples include "same-sex spouses" and "unmarried partners". Could someone help me identify the table(s) which includes the same-sex spouse information?

Answer (score 3):

This data is not readily available in the US Census right now. According to this [Nov. 2014 story from FiveThirtyEight.com](http://fivethirtyeight.com/features/the-census-still-doesnt-know-how-many-same-sex-couples-there-are/), new questions explicitly asking whether the respondent's spouse was same-sex or different were tested in 2015, but if that happened, presumably it was a limited test. The [archived 2015 questionnaire](http://www2.census.gov/programs-surveys/acs/methodology/questionnaires/2015/quest15.pdf) doesn't use the form shown in the 538 article, and neither does [the current (2016) version of the question](http://www2.census.gov/programs-surveys/acs/about/qbyqfact/2016/Relationship.pdf).

Remember that it has been less than a year since [Obergefell v. Hodges](https://www.oyez.org/cases/2014/14-556) was decided. I'm actually surprised that they were planning tests of the explicit same-sex question before then, considering the mix of legal statuses from state-to-state.

You've found what is probably the best page on the subject, and I think this is one of the places which the Census will keep up to date, despite the sad amount of content rot elsewhere on census.gov.

Comment: Just as a point of interest, here's a story about this released by the Cook County (Illinois) Clerk -- although unfortunately I can't find data in tabular form https://www.dnainfo.com/chicago/20150218/uptown/which-chicago-neighborhoods-have-most-same-sex-marriages-report